# Statistics Vocabulary - Trial?

Tags: probability, terminology

My textbook seems to use 'trial' in two different ways:

> That is, $P(A)$ represents the proportion of outcomes of a random experiment that terminate in the event $A$ as the number of trials of that experiment increases without bound.

From this usage, I gather that (1 trial) = (1 performed experiment)

> A fair six-sided die is rolled six times. If the face numbered $k$ is the outcome on roll $k$ for $k=1, 2, ..., 6$, we say that a match has occurred. The experient is called a success if at least one match occurs during the six trials. Otherwise, the experiment is called a failure.

Here, we seem to have six different trials within the same experiment.

Can somebody please clarify the meaning of trial for me?

Comment: It can mean either one.  Most words in most languages carry multiple meanings: you determine which one is intended from the context.  There's no harm in this example, which seems to create little risk of confusion.

Comment: @whuber I was under the impression that in statistics trial might be fundemental word which carried just one meaning (in the same way that 'random experiment' is a fundamental term with just one meaning).

Comment: This word does not have a fixed technical meaning in part, I suppose, because a sequence of trials from an experiment can be--and often is--considered as if it were a *single* experiment, and therefore becomes just one trial!

Comment: As whuber commented, a trial can have a bunch of different meanings. 
However, using your rationale, I'd say that usually an experiment will have many trials. And for me the sentence "as the number of trials of that experiment increases" implies that an experiment will have many trials.